# Disable webclips for Google Apps for Education Domain

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-for-education, google-email-settings-api

Edition: Google Apps for Education
Users Affected: All users
Problem Description: Do we need to disable webclips for Google Apps for Education Domain. We are using ADMIN SDK api to create and manage users. After user is created we are using EMAIL settings API(Gdata API) to disable the webclips. Do we need to do this ? Looks like webclips, ads for Google Apps for Education Domain is disabled by default by Google. Please do let me know on the same.

Comment: For Email settings api we are using ClientLogin auth and looks like thats getting retired. We need to move to OAuth2.0. So please let me know if we need to disable webclips for Education domain. I created a user and I didnt see webclips enabled for that user in gmail settings. Is that disabled by default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ads for Google Apps for Educations are disabled by default.

Check this link http://googleforwork.blogspot.com/2014/04/protecting-students-with-google-apps.html